# Crash in Android 6.0 x com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.native_deinit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface, android-6.0-marshmallow, qualcomm

I got this exception in GooglePlay ANR Crash log , This exception only occur in Android 6.0 devices. 
What is "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" Why I'm didn't found it in my code??

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [FinalizerWatchdogDaemon]
    Unity version     : 2018.4.2f1
    Device model      : LeMobile Le X526
    Device fingerprint: Letv/Le2_WW/le_s2_ww:6.0.1/IIXOSOP5801910121S/44:user/release-keys
    Caused by
      at com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.native_deinit (Native Method)
      at com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.finalize (Performance.java:263)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize (Daemons.java:202)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run (Daemons.java:185)
      at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Editor :

I found source code : 
https://pastebin.com/quBM3gVe
https://github.com/dzo/frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/org_codeaurora_Performance.cpp

I found this : https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions/issues/189 
someone get almost same crash log

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.native_deinit() (tried Java_com_qualcomm_qti_Performance_native_1deinit and Java_com_qualcomm_qti_Performance_native_1deinit__)**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.native_deinit() (tried Java_com_qualcomm_qti_Performance_native_1deinit and Java_com_qualcomm_qti_Performance_native_1deinit__)
             at com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.native_deinit(Native Method)
             at com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.finalize(Performance.java:263)
             at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:222)
             at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:209)
             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

==== Update ====

This Exception form `FinalizerWatchdogDaemon` So that exception probability is `TimeoutException` , is about Android GC , Finalize() timeout. But I still dont know what's going on.

Comment: can you share all crash logs

Comment: @MayurCoceptioni That's all I got , By the way this is crash in Unity Game

Comment: Is it possible the .so file in your APK _also_ has a `Java_native_deinit` symbol? Check with `nm`.

Comment: @Botje I found all *.so file form apk  `lib/arm64-v8a` , `lib/arneabi-v7a` , `lib/x86` , and not search any `Java_native_deinit method`
I use this command `$ objdump -TC *.so | grep deinit` to search